# Measuring effect size with two groups and one independent variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, effect-size, statsmodels

I have conducted a study in which I am trying to assess how fast participants recognize familiar objects shown within white noise. Given my results, I suspect that for a given level of coherence(more or less white noise), the reaction time of participants is generally about 5ms faster to faces than it is to cars. The standard deviation best describing my uncertainty about that difference is about 34ms. I wonder which measure of effect size I should use for this difference?